# Nearest Neighbour text classification

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor

I have two text files **(1) sample of bad words** and **(2) sample of good words.** Now I have perform nearest neighbor classification in which new word found will be classified as being good or bad.I want insight on how to approach this with my existing code. Thanks

```
class Words_Works():

def __init__(self):
    self.all_texts = {}
    self.categories = {}
    self.knn_results = {}
    self.stop_words = ['and','the','i','am','he','she','his',
                        'me','my','a','at','in','you','your',
                        'of','to','this','that','him','her',
                        'they','is','it','can','for','into',
                        'as','with','we','us','them','a', 
                        'it', 'on', 'so', 'too','k','the',
                        'but', 'are','though'
                        'very', 'here', 'even', 'from',
                        'then', 'than']

    self.leaf_words = ['s', 'es', 'ed', 'er', 'ly', 'ing']

def add_category(self,f,cat_name):
    f_in = open(f)
    self.text = f_in.read().lower()
    f_in.close()
    self.wordify()
    self.unstopify()
    self.unleafify()
    self.categories[cat_name] = {}
    for item  in self.unleaf:
        if self.categories[cat_name].has_key(item):
            self.categories[cat_name][item] += 1
        else:
            self.categories[cat_name][item] = 1


def load_categories(self):
    try:
        cat_db = open('tweetCategory.txt','rb')
        self.categories = cPickle.load(cat_db)
        cat_db.close()
        print 'File successfully loaded from categories db'
    except:
        print 'File not loaded from categories_db'


        # Finds the levenshtein's distance 
def levenshtein_distance(first, second):
"""Find the Levenshtein distance between two strings."""
if len(first) > len(second):
    first, second = second, first
    if len(second) == 0:
        return len(first)
        first_length = len(first) + 1
        second_length = len(second) + 1
        distance_matrix = [[0] * second_length for x in range(first_length)]
        for i in range(first_length):
            distance_matrix[i][0] = i
            for j in range(second_length):
               distance_matrix[0][j]=j
               for i in xrange(1, first_length):
                   for j in range(1, second_length):
                       deletion = distance_matrix[i-1][j] + 1
                       insertion = distance_matrix[i][j-1] + 1
                       substitution = distance_matrix[i-1][j-1]
                       if first[i-1] != second[j-1]:
                           substitution += 1
                           distance_matrix[i][j] = min(insertion, deletion, substitution)
    return distance_matrix[first_length-1][second_length-1]  

def add_text(self,f):
    f_in = open(f)
    self.text = f_in.read().lower()
    f_in.close()
    self.wordify()
    self.unstopify()
    self.unleafify()
    self.all_texts[f] = {}
    for item in self.unleaf:
        if self.all_texts[f].has_key(item):
            self.all_texts[f][item] += 1
        else:
            self.all_texts[f][item] = 1

def save_categories(self):
    cat_db = open('tweetCategory.txt','wb')
    cPickle.dump(cat_db,self.categories,-1)
    cat_db.close()

def unstopify(self):
    self.unstop = [item for item in self.words if item not in self.stop_words]

def unleafify(self):
    self.unleaf = self.unstop[:]
    for leaf in self.leaf_words:
        leaf_len = len(leaf)
        leaf_pattern = re.compile('%s$' % leaf)
        for i in range(len(self.unleaf)):
            if leaf_pattern.findall(self.unleaf[i]):
                self.unleaf[i] = self.unleaf[i][:-leaf_len]

def wordify(self):
    words_pattern = re.compile('//w+')
    self.words = words_pattern.findall(self.text)

def knn_calc(self):
    for text in self.all_texts.keys():
        self.knn_results[text] = {}
        for category in self.categories.keys():
            self.knn_results[text][category] = {}
            iterations = 0
            distance = 0
            for word in self.all_texts[text].keys():
                if word in self.categories[text].keys():

                    distance = levenshtein_distance(text,category)
                    self.knn_results[text][category]['Knn Distance'] = distance
                    self.knn_results [text][category]['Knn Iterations'] = iterations


def knn(self):
    for text in self.all_texts.keys():
        Result = None
        for category in self.categories.keys():
            if not result or self.knn_results[text][category]['Knn Distance'] < result:
                knn = category
                distance = self.knn_results[text][category]['Knn Distance']
                iterations = self.knn_results[text][category]['Knn Iterations']

                print 'File:',text
                print 'Knn:',category
                print 'Distance :', distance
                print 'Iterations :', iterations
                print 'End of nearest neighbour search'
```

**And the test case to try it out:**

```
mywork = Words_Works()

positive = 'positive.txt'
mywork.add_category(positive, 'Positive Tweets')               # Adding as category
negative = 'negative.txt'
mywork.add_category(negative, 'Negative Tweets')
neutral = 'neutral.txt'
mywork.add_category(neutral, 'Neutral Tweets')

for category in mywork.categories.keys():              # Print categories
    print category
    print mywork.categories[category]
    print
print

txts = ('samplegood.txt', 'samplebad.txt')                  # Creating list of files to

for text in txts:                                      # Adding them
    mywork.add_text(text)

for text in mywork.all_texts.keys():                   # Print texts
    print text
    print mywork.all_texts[text]
    print    
print

mywork.knn_calc()                                         # calculate knn

for files in mywork.knn_results.keys():                   # print detailed results
    print files
    for category in mywork.knn_results[files].keys():
        print category
        print mywork.knn_results[files][category]
    print
print    

mywork.knn()                                              # Display results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two pieces of advice: first, as noted by @YvesDaoust, you should use the edit distance, also known as Levenshtein distance. You can find it in the [python-Levenshtein package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.11.2).

Second, use the [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) or [doctest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) libraries in the standard library to test your code. It is a bad idea to use examples kept in external files to test your code, because a third person without access to those files (us, for instance) cannot know what is the input; avoid as well to print the output and manually inspect it, because this is slow, error-prone and again not reviewable by others.

Comment: I have implemented the edit_distance, any help that can be rendered to achieve my solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the Edit distance, you are not in Euclidean space. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: I have implemented the edit_distance, any help that can be rendered to achieve my solution.